# .Net configuration - How to override settings and custom sections in a mapped configuration file?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

If I have in myprogram.exe.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="fooSection" type="MyNamespace.MySection, My.Assembly"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar"/>
  </appSettings>
  <fooSection>
    <bar>
      <add baz="foo bar baz"/>
    </bar>
  </fooSection>
</configuration>
```

and I have in overrides.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="fooSection" type="MyNamespace.MySection, My.Assembly"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="BAZ"/>
  </appSettings>
  <fooSection>
    <bar>
      <add baz2="foo foo"/>
    </bar>
  </fooSection>
</configuration>
```

Is there any way to have this read into the core (or loaded) configuration, like you would get with the machine->app config file precendence?  (or even machine.config -> machine root web.config -> local app web.config)

In this example, I would like config.AppSettings["foo"] to be "BAZ" and fooSection to contain two items: "foo bar baz" and "foo foo".

I cannot find a way, and am guessing it may not be supported.  I've tried many permutations.

```
MySection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("foo") as MySection;

ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.LocalUserConfigFilename = // have tried this;
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = // have tried this
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("foo");

foo = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("foo") as MySection;
// will only have one item
foo = config.GetSection("foo") as MySection;
// will only have one item
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ever? I have similar requirement where i have to override the default config with client specific configs.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking to do this? This seems to me like you are trying to maybe deal with production configs? If that is the case, then I would suggest looking at .config transforms. In fact, Scott Hanselman wrote up a [good post on the subject](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx)

Otherwise, I do not believe that this is possible. Especially, with the flexibility in config transforms.

Comment: Thanks, Justin.  This may be useful in some situations.  Right now I run regression tests of a product, and can specify -config path\to.config to test certain functionality, so a change of the build philosophy could probably make this fit.

Comment: The other scenario, is that the program may not be run from a local path, but from a network share (easier distribution of software).  Say for instance it is run as a console app, or a Windows service - you could specify command line options, or direct to a configuration file that is tailored for the local host.

Comment: May it will help, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826744/how-to-share-configuration-file-for-web-and-window-application>